# ListTile.tileColor is late to render

Tags: flutter-layout

When ListView resizes, the selection is late to catch up.

Here is the code:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: controller.scrollController,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: controller.snapshots.value.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          tileColor: controller.selectedIndex.value == index
              ? Theme.of(context).selectedRowColor
              : null,
          title: _SnapshotListTitle(
            item: controller.snapshots.value[index],
            selected: index == controller.selectedIndex.value,
          ),
          onTap: () => controller.selectedIndex.value = index,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Code: https://github.com/flutter/devtools/blob/50ab9a87440f8a0b59ceb15cae34600384f5c42b/packages/devtools_app/lib/src/screens/memory/panes/diff/diff_pane.dart#L132

Video: https://github.com/flutter/devtools/pull/4260#issuecomment-1188500440

Answer (score 0):

Replaced ListTile with Container + InkWell to make it working:

```
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          color: controller.selectedIndex.value == index
              ? Theme.of(context).selectedRowColor
              : null,
          height: 40,
          child: InkWell(
            canRequestFocus: false,
            onTap: () => controller.selectedIndex.value = index,
            child: _SnapshotListTitle(
              item: controller.snapshots.value[index],
              selected: index == controller.selectedIndex.value,
            ),
          ),
        );
```